# Wifi drops again after ‎2017-‎12-‎16 Windows 10 update

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

So, I installed [Windows 10 update KB4054517, 2017-12-12](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4054517/windows-10-update-kb4054517) and [Windows 10 update KB4058043, 2017-12-16](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/4058043) (which I suspect may be the culprit but I don't know) and at about that time Wi-Fi started dropping like this (screenshot taken from uTorrent):

[image: enter link description here]

What I did:

1. **Checked power settings** and Wi-Fi was already at "maximum performance".
2. **Rolled back the driver** for Dell Wireless 1830 802.11ac from current 2017-10-18 version to some old 2016-01 version. Restarted the computer and it didn't help. Restored the driver to 1.566.0.2. My computer is Dell XPS 9550.
3. **Restarted the router**.
4. **Restarted the computer many times**.
5. **Repositioned the router to be very close to the laptop.**
6. **Changed my local IP to many other local IPs for test**.
7. Tried to find something in **Device Manager > Network adapters > Properties > Advanced** to see if maybe I can switch between 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz bands but there is no such option there.

Other devices:

1. iPhone reaches full 50+ mb/s on speedtest.net from the same Wi-Fi.
2. Macbook reaches full 50+ mb/s on speedtest.net from the same Wi-Fi.
3. Dell reaches from 0 mb/s to max 5 mb/s (and drops signal every minute).